# Is there a shortcut for assigning the current program to a specific spot in the task bar?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

In Window 7 you can drag/drop your running applications in the task bar to give them a specific order.  Is there a shortcut key combination that allows you to assign the current program to a specific location on the task bar?

Comment: If you pin the program it will have a specific position on the Taskbar.

Comment: @Karan I avoid having any programs pinned at all.  I launch every single program with my keyboard (namely, windows key + start typing 2 or 3 letters, hit enter).  I like to keep my taskbar clean of anything but actual running programs.

Comment: What you want can certainly be automated, but I don't know of any program that allows you to do so. Guess you'll have to write your own.

Answer (score 2):

**<kbd>Windows</kbd> + 0 - 9:** You can select an existing Taskbar Item and maximize.
**<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + 0 - 9:** You create a new tab / instance of the Program selected.
**<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0 - 9:** You open the Right-Click Menu for that Taskbar Item.
Beyond that there is no way to change the order with KB-Shortcuts.